# jquery doesn't save date as timestamp on hidden value

Tags: jquery

I use JQuery to save in hidden input timestamp.

When I execute followe command:

> console.log("Cur date in update function: "+cur_date);

In debug console I see: 1466946890859
This is variable (timastamp) which I put to some function. I need save this value in hidden input:

```
$('#dateinput').val(cur_date);
```

But in develop console I see that JQuery didn't save on right format:

```
 <input id="dateinput" type="hidden" name="date" value="Sun Jun 26 2016
 16:14:50 GMT+0300">
```

So, when I try in next time read this value, instead of timestamp I get format of date.

```
console.log("Date From hidden value: "+$('#dateinput').val());//-> show: Sun Jun 26 2016 16:14:50 GMT+0300
```

How it's right fix? Save on hidden input timestamp or convert full date format to timestamp?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no problem. See https://jsfiddle.net/wx7bg8ze/

Comment: You save string value in hidden input. And you see right result. But please look at my post. I save Date. And in hidden input I have date time format. So it's not work for me.

Comment: You setted value of input to `Sun Jun 26 2016
 16:14:50 GMT+0300` in html. However provide demo to checking what happen.

Comment: No! I don't setted value on format Sun Jun 26 2016 16:14:50 GMT+0300. Please look: when I print cur_date on console, I see timestamp: 1466946890859. But when I put this cur_date to hidden element: $('#dateinput').val(cur_date); I get format Sun Jun 26 2016 16:14:50 GMT+0300

Comment: When I save this way: $('#dateinput').val(cur_date.unix()); I see timestamp but not all: 1466949868 instead 1466949868225

Comment: This way also heven't worked for me: var datum = Date.parse(cur_date); $('#dateinput').val(datum/1000);

Comment: Do you use any date plugin?

Comment: I try modify this example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fast-selection-date-picker. 8 line on java script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115642/discussion-between-user3231442-and-mohammad).